# Run Application using Command without blocking Terminal

Tags: matlab

I have made some command (at /usr/bin) to Run Application like Matlab, Weka etc in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. While using Matlab command, it holds the Terminal until I close Matlab or Terminal (if I close Terminal, Matlab also closed). How can I avoid this problem, that means Matlab command will not hold terminal while working? Thank You.

The Following Format has worked before but suddenly not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

setsid /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Now Matlab just open the logo but no further work going on....

Comment: Has there been any recent update for Matlab that you recall ?

Comment: not exactly......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `nohup [CMD] &` is a good alternative. `nohup` frees the command from the terminal running it and makes it immune to terminal hangups.

Also, the command you posted opens a new session and immediately sends EOF with `</dev/null` which forces matlab to not accept any input from terminal. This might be an issue depending on how a given program executes upon opening. I also do not think `disown` serves any purpose here, as the & runs it in the background and setsid should free it from the terminal. `disown` does not disconnect the program from the terminal, it only removes it from the job list.  In any case, I'd use `nohup [CMD] &` as it does

1) separate the program from the terminal running it

2) closes standard input

3) redirects stdout and stderr to a separate file for examination instead of just sending it into the `/dev/null` abyss

4) `&` at the end puts it in the background

Comment: please upvote if helpful